# SQL Server - Intersect of two queries, both using WHERE Clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have `table1` and `table2`.

```
table1 contains ZipCode (varchar(12)), GeogCol1 (Geography)-spatial index
table2 contains ZipCode (varchar(12)), Product (varchar(12))
```

I need to return all `Product's` within a certain radius from a user provided `Zipcode ('90266')` that's assumed to be contained in both tables, display the `distance` from the `Zipcode` to each returned `Product` and give the user the option of sorting or reverse sorting the `Products` by the `distance` to the provided `Zipcode`.

Query 1- Here's my radius distance query:

```
SELECT h.* 
FROM table1 g  
JOIN table1 h on g.Zipcode <> h.Zipcode AND g.Zipcode = '90266' AND h.Zipcode <> '90266' 
WHERE g.GeogCol1.STDistance(h.GeogCol1)<=(10 * 1609.344) 
ORDER BY g.GeogCol1.STDistance(h.GeogCol1)
```

Query 2- Here's my Product query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table2 
WHERE (Active = 1) AND (ProductName LIKE '%54%')
```

Also, is it better if I put the `GeogCol1` spatial index in `table2` along with each products other information so the query can be done against a single table?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, your first query excludes the current zip code, so I have no go to the next zip code to get the product even if it is available in my zip code. Doesn't seem right to me.

Anyway

```
SELECT t2.Zipcode
      ,t2.Product
FROM table1 g  
     INNER JOIN 
     table1 h ON g.Zipcode <> h.Zipcode 
                 AND 
                 g.Zipcode = '90266' 
     INNER JOIN
     table2 t2 ON (t2.Active=1) 
                   AND 
                   (t2.ProductName LIKE '%54%')
                   AND
                   g.Zipcode=t2.Zipcode
WHERE g.GeogCol1.STDistance(h.GeogCol1)<=(10 * 1609.344) 
ORDER BY g.GeogCol1.STDistance(h.GeogCol1)
```

The third condition on the self-join is redundant by the first condition.

DO NOT put them in the same table- you will be denormalising your data.

Comment: I think this still begs the question: What is the right Index or set of Indices to ensure this query is fast?